# how to remove multiple elements in array in libgdx

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I am using libgdx, i have an arraylist of ball class created by me. i am trying to delete balls with same color at a time. due to shift in position of elements in array after deletion of element, this  leave some element undelete.
so i am using Snapshot Arrays
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/SnapshotArray.html

according to documentation array size and indexes will not change if we write our loop between array.begin() and array.end() methods. 
so i declared snapshot arrays

```
SnapshotArray<Ball> balls;
```

and my deletion method is

```
 private void removeVillianGroups(int color){
        Ball[] ball=balls.begin();
        for(int i=0;i<balls.size;i++){

            if(balls.get(i).getColor()==color){
                ball.removeValue(balls[i],true);

            }
        }
        balls.end();
    }
```

and i am getting error with casting

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lcom.mygames.haloween.Entity.Ball;
```

at this line above

```
Ball[] ball=balls.begin();
```

So here i created my array,basically i divide my screen width into six equal part, to have 6 column of balls

```
 private void createVillians() {

      for (int color=0;color<4;color++)//create 4 diffirent color balls in 4 rows
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)//each row contan 6 same color balls
{
       balls.add(new Ball(viewport,new Vector2(i*viewport.getWorldWidth()/6,
               0-c*viewport.getWorldWidth()/6),color));

//Ball class just draw balls according their color between 0 to 3.
        }
    }
```

[image: this is what generate by this array]

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful It returns a `T[]` (i.e. `Ball[]`). @OP: are you sure you're not using a raw type? Can we have more code? Also, "due to shift in position of elements in array after deletion of element" - why not use a dynamic collection like `Array` or `List` instead?

Comment: If you see example on the api page it is using Object[] as raw type, which makes me think it is historical implementation and 'T[]' support added sometime after, in this case can you share library version if it is the latest one against this api?

Comment: I already tried Array list and delayedRemoval Array too,due shifting after deletion iterator skips next element as its position is now deleted array. and in snapshot array, my type is  defined class Ball, which just draw a ball sprite.see my goal is just to delete multiple array at same time with same color,  I don't think more code needed but if need i will post

Comment: Can you tell me your Twitter account? Can we be friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use a regular ArrayList and iterate backwards:

```
ArrayList<Ball> balls;

private void removeVillianGroups(int color){
  for(int i = balls.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(balls.get(i).getColor()==color){
            balls.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your original code was giving a CCE is that the libgdx Array/SnapshotArray class returns an Object[] if you did not pass in the class type in its constructor. SnapshotArray is potentially faster than Array or ArrayList if you are removing several items at once.

You seem to be mixing up the snapshot array with the temporary array, as well. And note that `balls.size` is not stable during iteration, so you should cache it. Your code should look like this:

```
private void removeVillianGroups(int color){
    Ball[] ball=balls.begin();
    for(int i=0, n=balls.size; i<n; i++){
        if(ball[i].getColor()==color){
            balls.removeIndex(i);
        }
    }
    balls.end();
}
```

Comment: I followed you, but i don't know why CCE still exist at 2nd line of your code.

Comment: Because in Java generics are merely syntactic sugar. The Array class doesn't actually know what type of object it contains so it is using Object internally. An Object array cannot be cast to another type of array. If you pass the class type to the Array constructor, then it will know the type, and can use a Ball array internally instead of Object. Use balls=new SnapshotArray<Ball>(Ball.class);

Comment: This method will crashed with `ClassCastException`. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5076

Comment: @Sergey That's not a bug. As the javadocs for Array explain (and my comment right above), you must explicitly pass in the Class to the appropriate constructor if you want the backing array to be a type other than Object[].